Memory remains allocated after running parallel python jobs (with either joblib or multiprocessing)
I'm running parallel code to analyse very large volumes of data. I noticed that when it's done I'm usually left with very large amounts of allocated memory that can't be freed without restarting the kernel. Occasionally this led to OOM errors during subsequent analysis stages.
The simplest way to reproduce it is to run:
import numpy as np
import psutil
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

print(f'Initial memory usage: {psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / (2 ** 20)} MB')

def proc():
    return np.ones(50000)

res = Parallel(n_jobs=6, verbose=1)(delayed(proc)() for d in range(20000))

print(f'After running parallel jobs: {psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / (2 ** 20)} MB')

for i in range(len(res)):
    res[i] = None

del res

print(f'After deleting data: {psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / (2 ** 20)} MB')

A typical output is:
Initial memory usage: 57.28125 MB
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 6 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done 100 tasks      | elapsed:    0.3s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done 4468 tasks      | elapsed:    3.7s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done 12468 tasks      | elapsed:    9.8s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done 20000 out of 20000 | elapsed:   15.8s finished
After running parallel jobs: 7806.484375 MB
After deleting data: 6518.30859375 MB

The amount retained after deleting the data is variable between executions of the same code, but it never goes back to the initial usage. It scales with the size of the data returned by the task (in this case, 50000 x 8 bytes).
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, This is my env:
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
_openmp_mutex             5.1                       1_gnu  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
ca-certificates           2024.3.11            h06a4308_0  
intel-openmp              2023.1.0         hdb19cb5_46306  
joblib                    1.4.0            py39h06a4308_0  
ld_impl_linux-64          2.38                 h1181459_1  
libffi                    3.4.4                h6a678d5_0  
libgcc-ng                 11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libgomp                   11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libstdcxx-ng              11.2.0               h1234567_1  
mkl                       2023.1.0         h213fc3f_46344  
mkl-service               2.4.0            py39h5eee18b_1  
mkl_fft                   1.3.8            py39h5eee18b_0  
mkl_random                1.2.4            py39hdb19cb5_0  
ncurses                   6.4                  h6a678d5_0  
numpy                     1.26.4           py39h5f9d8c6_0  
numpy-base                1.26.4           py39hb5e798b_0  
openssl                   3.0.13               h7f8727e_0  
pip                       23.3.1           py39h06a4308_0  
psutil                    5.9.0            py39h5eee18b_0  
python                    3.9.19               h955ad1f_0  
readline                  8.2                  h5eee18b_0  
setuptools                68.2.2           py39h06a4308_0  
sqlite                    3.41.2               h5eee18b_0  
tbb                       2021.8.0             hdb19cb5_0  
tk                        8.6.12               h1ccaba5_0  
tzdata                    2024a                h04d1e81_0  
wheel                     0.41.2           py39h06a4308_0  
xz                        5.4.6                h5eee18b_0  
zlib                      1.2.13               h5eee18b_0

Tried the following with very similar results:

Using multiprocessing.Pool.map instead of joblib
Running it on Windows 11 instead of Ubuntu
Using %xdel instead of del to delete the data
Running gc.collect() in the end, and within the proc function
Waiting between deleting the variable and checking memory usage
Different joblib versions (I know there used to be a leak problem in earlier versions)


I cannot reproduce the problem on Windows 10 with CPython 3.8.1, Numpy 1.24.4 and joblib 1.3.2. I also cannot reproduce this on Debian Linux with CPython 3.11.6, Numpy 1.26.4 and joblib 1.4.0. Thus, this is certainly related to your environment. Please share the version of the modules or test with other versions. Also : is the size still increasing after like 3-4 runs?

I also cannot reproduce this on another very different machine with a fresh newly installed Windows 11 (version 10.0.22631 build 22631) and with the latest CPython and PIP modules: CPython 3.12.3, Numpy 1.26.4 and joblib 1.4.0. Note the first machine (in the first comment) has an Intel i5-9600KF CPU with 32 GiB of RAM and the second one (in this comment) has an AMD Ryzen 5700U CPU with 16 GiB of RAM.

I originally had this problem on Ubuntu (running on a 64 GiB RAM, i9-10900X machine, where I actually need this to work) with the module versions listed above (Python 3.9.19, Numpy 1.26.4, joblib 1.4.0). On this config the RAM left allocated does not seem to monotonically increase between runs, but if I downgrade to joblib 1.2.0 it does increase, up to a point. I also tried several newer Python versions (inc 3.11.9), but could not find a combination that would eliminate the problem on this machine.

Also tried on a Windows 11 laptop (AMD Ryzen 9 5900HX, 32 GiB), and now realised that with an identical modules as above (ie joblib 1.4.0) the issue is not reproduced, but it does show up again when downgrading to joblib 1.2.0, where it is solved by calling gc.collect() (which does not work on the Ubuntu machine!)

I can also reproduce the behaviour I'm seeing on my Ubuntu desktop on two separate Linux-based clusters (RHEL Server release 7.8 with the same module versions as above, CentOS Linux 7 with Python 3.8.5, Numpy 1.24.4, joblib 1.4.0).  In short, it seems to be associated with Linux

Ok. 1. Can you try to use a relatively new version of CPython (which is responsible to do allocations then done by the libc). Like >3.11.6 (like on my Linux which do not have the issue). 2. Can you try another libc using LD_PRELOAD=jemalloc.so after installing jemalloc (you may need to add it in your path or use an absolute path). I expect the second one to solve your problem if the memory stabilize (hence my previous question about that).

Tried with CPython 3.11.9 and 3.12.3, same results. LD_PRELOAD=libjemalloc.so does change the behaviour, but doesn't completely solve the problem - more memory is allocated during the run (4G instead of 3G), and about half of it is released when deleting the object. The rest is still locked

I think you should use tools like valgrind to see if there is a memory leak somewhere but I expect the memory to be temporary conserved by the allocator (which is a normal behaviour for many reasons like performance). Some allocators are more conservative than others. The one of Windows is not conservative but often much slower than the default one on linux (glibc). What matters is whether the memory usage increase between multiple runs. If it does, then there is likely a leak. If it does not then this is normal. Regarding whether this is the first or the second, solutions are different.
